# How do I estimate opening call auction order book for equities?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, market-microstructure, exchange

The opening call auction crossing order book is partially sealed, i.e. only the specialist can see quotes.

Is there a stock exchange where this data is available later to simulate the matching algorithm and the open?

Is there any provider selling order flow covering the open auction too (covering at least part of the whole market)?